# Best practice about multiplayer game with nodejs

Tags: node.js, nodes, multiplayer

i search the "best practice" to create a simple multiplayer browser game. i have choose nodejs for the backend and maybe Phaser for the front. But i have a question about the algorithm. 
In each tutorial the server respond after a client event. But a lot of generic article speak about a loop which send world data at regular interval to all client (for example the [valve article](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking)).

So what is true ? What is the correct procedure ? It depends of the game type ?

For your information i want to do a simple twin stick shooter with a little world where we must survive as long as possible. And i want to do a cooperative game.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to distinguish between

- updates directly affecting your player which are triggered by actions of other players
- and updates which are triggered by actions of your player

If you build your app using Node.js, I assume you are going to work with one web socket connect per client.

You can send data over the web socket connection any time in both directions. There is no restriction at all, as long as the amount of data is moderate.

The server actively sending world data in a loop (implemented using `setInterval` in JavaScript) is definitely a good choice for informing players if they are affected by actions of other players. You can also use the loop to let the server respond to actions of your player.

If you assume the loop always informs the clients in the same order (e.g. client #1, client #2, client #3, client #1,... and so on), you could optimize performance by preferring clients that are active right now, and are doing heavy activity (that is "the server responds after a client event"). Particularly if you have many players in the game, this could improve user experience.

Comment: Ok thanks, so if i understand well. For you an ai will be moved by a loop which send data by interval ? And user move not automatically by the loop.

Comment: Yes. But of course you may set the interval delay to zero: So that still there is an interval between messages sent to clients, but it is as short as possible. The shorter or longer delay between messages gives your Node.js process time to take breathers. Thus you will need them.

Comment: What do you mean by "user move not automatically by the loop"?